# INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY: invalid cross reference id

Tags: apex, trigger, email-template, permissions

I'm triggering an email with `OnAfterInsert`. Inside the method, I have access to all the necessary data to send the actual e-mail:

- emailtemplateId
- whoId
- whatId
- internalEmailAddrs
- externalEmailAddrs
- orgwideEmailId

Now, this trigger is activated after I insert a new `Account`. but while trying to send the e-mail, I notice that I have the in the title mentioned error. While digging some deeper, I notice that the ID of the `Account` does not exists anymore. I guess this entry has been rolled back, due to this error.

I've been digging in the permissions, and every permission (that I know of) is correct.

My last guess is that the guest user (anonymous profile) does not have access to the email template I'm trying to use. But I have no idea where I could double-check this.

Here is the code of the trigger:

```
public void OnAfterInsert(Account[] newAccounts){
    Id orgwideEmailId = null;
    List<OrgWideEmailAddress> orgWideEmailAddresses = [select id from OrgWideEmailAddress LIMIT 1];
    if(orgWideEmailAddresses.size() > 0) {
        orgwideEmailId = orgWideEmailAddresses[0].Id;
    }
    String selectedTemplateId = GlobalUtility.emailTemplates.get(
            GlobalUtilityConstants.EMAILTEMPLATE_PARTNERSELECTED_APINAME
    );

    String whoId = null;
    List<String> internalEmailAddrs = new List<String>();

    Set<Id> parentAccounts = new Set<Id>();
    for(Account acc : newAccounts){
        parentAccounts.add(acc.ParentId);
    }

    Map<Id, Account> parentAccountMap = new Map<Id, Account>([
            SELECT
                    Id,
                    Contact_Email__c,
                    Email__c
            FROM
                    Account
            WHERE
                    Id in :parentAccounts
    ]);
    Map<Id, String> parentEmailMap = new Map<Id,String>();

    for(Account parent : parentAccountMap.values()){
        if(parentEmailMap.containsKey(parent.Id)){
            // already processed this parent.
            continue;
        }

        if(parent.Contact_Email__c != null){
            parentEmailMap.put( parent.Id, parent.Contact_Email__c);
            continue;
        }

        if(parent.Email__c != null){
            parentEmailMap.put( parent.Id, parent.Email__c);
            continue;
        }
    }

    for( Account newAccount : newAccounts ) {

        String whatId = newAccount.Id;
        String selectedParentId = newAccount.ParentId;

        // Parent changed
        if( selectedParentId != null ) {
            List<String> externalEmailAddrs = new List<String>{parentEmailMap.get(selectedParentId)};


            ContactForm_Controller.doSentMail(
                    selectedTemplateId,
                    whoId,
                    whatId,
                    internalEmailAddrs,
                    externalEmailAddrs,
                    orgwideEmailId
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Did someone experience the same issue? Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you have to collect accountid right. parentAccounts.add(acc.id); why you are collecting parent accountid

Comment: There are different types of accounts. One is a customer, which needs a partner. That's why I collect eventual parent accounts.

Comment: On which line of code you are getting the error?

Comment: `ContactForm_Controller.doSentMail()` --> messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate() that's the stacktrace.

Comment: can you please put system.debug log before ContactForm_Controller.doSentMail. Please print all the values. where you declared internalEmailAddrs,externalEmailAddrs????

Comment: I've already done that. All the values were visible. But then I noticed when I tried to lookup the account ID, that this was no longer available. I got an error saying that this data was either removed or never existed.
In the code, we're doing a try catch with a rollback when it fails. we catch the already mentioned error.

Comment: To check email template permissions you have to edit the folder the template is stored in.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: To me it looks like my guest user does not have access to the relatedID of the account. I'm out of options. Every permission looks to be ok. Are there any other rules which might affect this?